# diagnostic_msg/DiagnosticStatus should have "stale"?

Tags: ros, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought I ask this question before submitting ticket [on github](http://goo.gl/MaSW6) since I'm not yet sure 100%.

Why does msg type `diagnostic_msg/DiagnosticStatus` not have level of operations `STALE`?

`DiagnosticStatus` [defines 3 levels of operations (from 0 to 2)](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/DiagnosticStatus.html). But `GenericAnalyzer` in `diagnostic_aggregator` [publishes level 3, or stale](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/diagnostic_aggregator/html/generic__analyzer_8cpp_source.html) (I recognized this while running `turtlebot_gazebo/launch/turtlebot_empty_world.launch`).

Assuming it's recommended to extend `GenericAnalyzer` when implementing your own robot, the cleanest solution would to include `stale` in the msg format imho but how does this sound?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47438/diagnostic_msg/diagnosticstatus-should-have-%22stale%22?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-04**:
I believe `stale` is when the message is not published at all, hence there is no code for it in the message, itself.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-04**:
This is how it is implemented (last time I checked), so it is never send by the program the diagnostic originated from. The aggregator adds this.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-05**:
It's never sent from the origin, but if we're designating "3" as "STALE" then we should still enumerate it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-05**:
If that is a quasi-standard, then yes, it should be in the message before it becomes commonly used differently. The only problem is that it does not make a lot of sense for a diagnostic component to set the status to STALE.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-05**:
Missing data, etc. should be a WARN or ERROR. For a supervisor it does make sense. So this should be documented properly to not get confused, i.e. STALE is not sensor stale, but component/driver stale.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-11-05**:
@dornhege and all, looks like we've come to conclusion - to add appropriate document to avoid confusion (ie. no change to the msg type). But where? Analyzer's doc? Or msg type's?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-05**:
@IsaacS, I do think it should go in the message type. Either that or to really fix this, `diagnostic_aggregator` should do something different with stale data. I don't think we should ever be setting an enumeration mode that isn't defined as such in the message type.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-11-05**:
@jbohren oh ok, so you're on "modifying msg type" side. Then I now feel this comment area isn't the best appropriate place to continue discussion. Is it ok to start a discussion on users' ML for such a small (but not trivial) change like this?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-05**:
Well, since this is a change that will be completely backwards-compatible, it probably just merits adding the definition in a fork of `common_msgs` on github and then attaching it to an enhancement ticket with a link to this thread. Then the discussion can happen there with the maintainers.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-05**:
+1 for putting it in the msg definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That *is* odd. I wouldn't be surprised if it's just because a STALE status was an afterthought and never got put back into the message def. It seems ticket-worthy, i'd say report it.

Update:
I've reported it here (with a pull request): https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/pull/3

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-11-06**:
+1 for the report on behalf of me (thought I was responsible for it)